# C# searching for new Tool for the tool box, how to template this code

Tags: c#, algorithm, refactoring

All i have something i have been trying to do for a while and have yet to find a good strategy to do it, i am not sure C# can even support what i am trying to do.

Example imagine a template like this, repeated in manager code overarching cocept function Returns a result consisting of a success flag and error list.

```
       public Result<Boolean> RemoveLocation(LocationKey key)
        {
           List<Error> errorList = new List<Error>();
           Boolean result = null;
           try{
                result  = locationDAO.RemoveLocation(key);
           }catch(UpdateException ue){
               //Error happened less pass this back to the user!
               errorList = ue.ErrorList;
           }

           return new Result<Boolean>(result, errorList);
        }
```

Looking to turn it into a template like the below where Do Something is some call (preferably not static) that returns a Boolean.  I know i could do this in a stack sense, but i am really looking for a  way to do it via object reference.

```
        public Result<Boolean> RemoveLocation(LocationKey key)
        {
             var magic =  locationDAO.RemoveLocation(key);

             return ProtectedDAOCall(magic);
        }
        public Result<Boolean> CreateLocation(LocationKey key)
        {
             var magic =  locationDAO.CreateLocation(key);

             return ProtectedDAOCall(magic);
        }


        public Result<Boolean> ProtectedDAOCall(Func<..., bool> doSomething)
        {
           List<Error> errorList = new List<Error>();
           Boolean result = null;
           try{
                result  = doSomething();
           }catch(UpdateException ue){
               //Error happened less pass this back to the user!
               errorList = ue.ErrorList;
           }

           return new Result<Boolean>(result, errorList);
        }
```

If there is any more information you may need let me know.

I am interested to see what someone else can come up with.

---

**Marc solution applied to the code above**

```
    public Result<Boolean> CreateLocation(LocationKey key)
    {
        LocationDAO locationDAO = new LocationDAO();
        return WrapMethod(() => locationDAO.CreateLocation(key));
    }


    public Result<Boolean> RemoveLocation(LocationKey key)
    {
        LocationDAO locationDAO = new LocationDAO();
        return WrapMethod(() =>  locationDAO.RemoveLocation(key));
    }


    static Result<T> WrapMethod<T>(Func<Result<T>> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return func();
        }
        catch (UpdateException ue)
        {
            return new Result<T>(default(T), ue.Errors);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't like the look of that exception wrapping, btw. Exceptions *already* bubble and results *already* get returned. You don't need to invent a new metaphor for that.

Comment: this was an example, the idea is what i needed. There is more pruning logic that goes on to clean up the exception that eventually gets exposed to the user.

Comment: I suggest to move `LocationDAO locationDAO = new LocationDAO();` to WrapMethod. See below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
public Result<Boolean> RemoveLocation(LocationKey key)
{
    return WrapMethod(() => locationDAO.RemoveLocation(key));
}
static Result<T> WrapMethod<T>(Func<T> func) {
    try
    {
        return new Result<T>(func());
    }
    catch (SomeExceptionBase ex)
    {
        return new Result<T>(ex.ErrorList);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new Result<T>((List<Error>)null);
    }
}
```

and (minimum shown)

```
class Result<T>
{
    private Result(bool isError, T value, List<Error> erors) { }
    public Result(T value) : this(false, value, null){ }
    public Result(List<Error> errors) : this(true, default(T), errors) { }
}
class SomeExceptionBase : Exception
{
    public List<Error> ErrorList { get; private set; }
}
```

(although if I *had* to do this I'd probably do something more interesting with exceptions that don't happen to be `SomeExceptionBase`)

Comment: Still testing it out, but with some minor teaks WrapMethod signature should be Result<T> (you might want to edit) 

 WrapMethod<T>(Func<Result<T>> func) {


Thanks. Once i validate everything is functional i will mark.

Comment: @Nix - I'm not convinced, you know. `Func<bool>` works fine...? That is kinda the point, isn't it? To turn "something that returns `bool` " (i.e. `Func<bool>` into `Result<bool>`?

Comment: i think the misunderstanding is that the dao returns a result<bool>

Comment: i posted solution above, hopefully it clears up what i was trying to do(frustratingly simple).

Answer (score 0):

We have the following in our project, it looks very similar

```
        public TResult DoCall<TResult,TProvider>(Func<TProvider, TResult> action) where TProvider : class, IProvider
        {
            TResult ret = default(TResult);
            try
            {
                var prov = (TProvider) ModelManagerProvider.GetProviderByType(typeof(TProvider));
                ret = action(prov);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ThrowErrorTool.ThrowError(ex);
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

and here is how we call it

```
        public bool UpdateAdverseEventSection(AdverseEventsDTO aeDTO)
        {
            return DoCall((AdverseEventsProvider r) => r.UpdateAdverseEventSection(aeDTO));
        }
```

Comment: Sorry i think this is a little too much, but it is a good example, if you could make it more generic it would help... the thing i dont need is the concept (in ur code) of a TProvider.  I just have some action i want to execute, no need to pass it.


yours is much more generic then i need.

Answer (score 0):

```
static Result<T> WrapMethod<T>(Func<LocationDao, Result<T>> func) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        var l = new LocationDao();
        return func(l); 
    } 
    catch (UpdateException ue) 
    { 
        return new Result<T>(default(T), ue.Errors); 
    } 
} 
public Result<Boolean> RemoveLocation(LocationKey key)     
{                  
    return WrapMethod((l) =>  l.RemoveLocation(key));     
}
```

Comment: that's why we have TProvider in our example