# Method passed in as parameter to a Method C#2.0

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

If I have a piece of code such as this:

```
private void DoOperations(//method passed in)
{
    executeA();
    executeB();

    // run method passed in to DoOpertions()

    executeC();

}
```

Is it possible to pass in a method as a paramter? The method may have X number of parameters itself?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# searching for new Tool for the tool box, how to template this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554413/c-searching-for-new-tool-for-the-tool-box-how-to-template-this-code)

Comment: When you say "The method may have X number of parameters", then I think you need to identify who (i.e. which piece of code) knows about those parameters.  Is it the DoOperations method that knows about them?  If so, then you likely want to pass a delegate with either the exact method signature you need or one that can take an array of parameters, such as in James Curran's answer.  Is it the caller of DoOperations that knows?  Then you might want to pass in an anonymous method as an `Action` or `Func<>` to the DoOperations method, such as in Jamiec's, Nenad's, or Nix's answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delegate void FunctionX(params object[] args);

private void DoOperations(FunctionX executeX) 
{ 
    executeA(); 
    executeB(); 

    executeX("any", "number", "of", "params");

    executeC(); 

} 
void MyFunction(params object[] p)
{
      // do stuff
}


DoOperations(MyFunction);
```

Comment: Don't like it, but it works.  Why not give more structure/typing.... object[] p   ?  (i know @james curran this isn't your question...) ...

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a delegate. Delegate is a method pointer, with the same signature as the method it is referencing.

See more at [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Nenad's answer, there are a number of built-in delegates in the .Net framework which you should try to use as much as possible, rather than re-inventing your own delegates that do the same thing.

- [System.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx)
- [System.Action(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)
- [System.Action(T1, T2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549311.aspx)
- ...
- [System.Func(TResult)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx)
- [System.Func(T, TResult)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)
- ...

Use the Action delegate if the delegate doesn't have a return value, otherwise use the Func delegates, each are overloaded with up to 4 input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is, for no parameters you want `Action`[1]

```
private void DoOperations(Action action)
{
  action();
}    
//usage    
DoAction( new Action(SayHello)  );

private void SayHello()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
}
```

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

Comment: The lambda is not compatible with c# 2.0, they were introduced with c# 3.0 (.net 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [anonymous functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx).

Checkout this post [C# searching for new Tool for the tool box, how to template this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554413/c-searching-for-new-tool-for-the-tool-box-how-to-template-this-code)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can define delegate  and DoOperatios() function with argument of that type. `enter code here`

```
delegate void AsFunction(string str, string str);// as many arguments as you want
public DoOperations(AsFunction asFunction)
{

        asFunction("hello1", "hello2");

}
```